# How do I show custom search results in odoo?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

I have created this method in my Program model:

```
@api.multi
def get_results(self):

    q = "select * from program_program where id_year = 1"
    self.env.cr.execute(q)
    res = self.env.cr.dictfetchall()
    result = self.env['program.program'].browse([row['id_viti'] for row in res])
    print(result)
    return result
```

I have created an action server:

```
    <record id="program" model="ir.actions.server">

<field name="name">First year program</field>

<field name="condition">True</field>

<field name="type">ir.actions.server</field>

<field name="model_id" ref="model_program_program" />

<field name="state">code</field>

<field name="code">action = model.get_results()</field>

</record>
```

And a menuItem :

```
  <menuitem id="year_1"
          name="First year"
          action="program"
/>
```

So the `get_results` method is called on menu item click. I want to be able to show the results of the method on my page.  I get this error :
`AttributeError: 'program.program' object has no attribute 'setdefault'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method should return a window action not a record set (result of search), and use a domain to filter the records:

```
   @api.multi
   def get_results(self):
       # just to simplify the code using Odoo APIs
       ids = self.env['program.program'].search([('id_year','=', 1)]).mapped('id_viti.id')
       return {
        'name':_("Programs of year 1"),
        'view_mode': 'tree,form',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'res_model': 'program.program',
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'domain': [('id', 'in', ids)],
        'context': self._context,
    }
```

Sorry for any syntax erros.